# C# not properly binding menu items

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hello I have a model method that looks like this.

```
 public string menuItems(bool drop)
        {

            var baseUrl = IGT.baseUrl;// string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority, HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppVirtualPath);

                string addmore = "<a class='dropdown-item' href=" + baseUrl + "DODetails/Create?orderID=" + ID.ToString() + ">Add More</a>";        
                string changestatus = "<a class='dropdown-item' href=" + baseUrl + "DisposalOrders/ChangeStatus/" + ID.ToString() + ">Change Status</a>";
                string details = "<a class='dropdown-item' href=" + baseUrl + "DisposalOrders/Details?id=" + ID.ToString() + ">Details</a>";
                string delete = "<a class='dropdown-item' href=" + baseUrl + "DisposalOrders/Delete?id=" + ID.ToString() + ">Delete</a>";
                string edit = "<a class='dropdown-item' href=" + baseUrl + "DisposalOrders/Edit?id=" + ID.ToString() + ">Edit</a>";
                string notes = "<a class='dropdown-item' href=" + baseUrl + "DisposalOrders/Notes/" + ID.ToString() + ">Notes</a>";
                //string delim = " | ";
                switch (Status)
                {
                    case DOStatus.Pending:
                        return addmore + " | " + edit + " | " + details + " | " + changestatus + " | " + delete + " | " + notes;
                        //return String.Concat(addmore, delim, changestatus, delim, delete, delim, details, delim, edit, delim, notes);
                    case DOStatus.Disposed:
                        return details + notes;           
                };
                return details;


        }
```

And a view page that returns those values by doing this

```
 <p>
    @Html.Raw(Model.menuItems(false)) | @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
 </p>
```

I have done this with other pages in my site and it looks like this

[image: What I want]

But what mine currently does is

[image: What it does]

I don't know if it's a system bug or something wrong with my code or what. Just confused at what the issue is right now

Here is my Markup

[image: Markup]

Comment: Do you have any styling(css etc.) going on that differs to other pages?

Comment: Not that I can find. And I tried moving that view code to the top of my page to see what it does and it still does the same thing. But the view pages call the method the same way and the method layout is identical besides the names of menu items @Greg

Comment: Sounds to me like its some sort of styling if it works on other pages and you are using identical methods etc. Im not sure what browser you are using but try use dev tools of your browser to inspect the <p> tag and <a> tags. Try disabling some of the active css class's that show

Comment: Sorry forgot to add, would you be able to add the markup that is created?

Comment: Sorry I'm relatively new to this, what do you mean by markup? Like the entire view? I have commented everything out besides that line and it still does the same thing. So I figure its not properly combining in the method or that the <p> tag is incorrect But I use <p> tag in my other pages doing the same thing and it works. @Greg

Comment: No problem, so when i say markup i mean HTML that is produce. You can view this by right clicking your web page in a browser and view source or inspect element. Or you can print your Model.menu items out as a string and show that.

Comment: @Greg Okay I added it

Comment: Cheers, im assuming thats chrome, and your inspecting the elements for it. Sorry to be a pain but could you include the styles tab that shows in the right hand side?
Should be looking at what css class "dropdown-item" is doing and if there are any styles targeting <a> or <p> tags

Comment: @Greg Oh yeah that dropdown-item has to be the cause! I think I know whats wrong!

Comment: @greg that dropdown-item has to be the cause! I think I know whats wrong! When I copied from the other site pages menu method I originally copied the "dropdown" menu and not the normal menu. Thanks for the help!